# lateinit property context has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a class which gets a `context` and `uri` and sets them in a `MediaMetadatRetriever` as `dataSource`. The problem is that I initialize context property with `withContext` function, but it seems to not being initialized and it ends up with a `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException`. Any help is appreciated.

**Class:**

```
class MyClass: Thread() {

    private lateinit var context: Context
    private lateinit var uri: Uri
    private val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()

    override fun run() {
        setRetriever()
    }

    fun withContext(context: Context) {
        this.context = context
    }

    fun withUri(uri: Uri) {
        this.uri = uri
    }

    fun setRetriever() {
        retriever.setDataSource(context, uri)
    }

    fun startThread() {
        MyClass().start()
    }
}
```

**Main Activity:**

```
val myClass = MyClass()
myClass.withContext(this)
myClass.withUri(uri)
myClass.startThread()
```

**Exception:**

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property context has not been initialized
```

Comment: @Eugene I checked it in source, it was correct

Comment: @Soroush can you show the whole logcat?

Comment: @Soroush, something is missing cause with a simple example such case works fine! Maybe you're calling `myClass` somewhere before init or smthng?

Comment: @Demigod I updated the post. MyClass extends Thread. Does it make any difference?

Comment: @Soroush, your method `start` creates new instance of `myClass` without initialization.

Comment: is the `start()` method correct now? start creates a new instance of `MyClass`...

Comment: @Soroush why don't you include the real class of yours and not some stripped down example of what you think consists of the problem?

Comment: @Demigod it'll be okay if I replace it with `this.start()` ?

Comment: myClass.startThread() throws the exception possibly because it creates another instance of MyClass()

Comment: @Soroush, yeah. Or just `start()`.

Comment: @Demigod Thanks the problem is gone. You can write an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Soroush, glad it helped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when call method `startThread()` you're creating new object every time with uninitialized property.

```
fun startThread() {
    MyClass().start()
}
```

You should replace `MyClass().start()` with `this.start()`